# How to display multiple Gauge instances

Tags: javascript

I've written some JavaScript code which produces two animating Gauges. Ideally I would like to display multiple Gauges at the same time with varying values say 100%, 50% and 25%.

Currently the only way I can display another Gauge is by coping the code again and renaming the variables. This doesn't exactly follow the dry methodology I know. However I have started using an Object constructor but the Gauge on the right keeps running/counting infinitely. I'm not sure why or whether in fact what I'm doing is correct. Does anyone have any suggestions. Thanks.

```
let ctx = document.getElementById('canvasOne').getContext('2d');
let al = 0;
let startPos = 4.72;
let cw = ctx.canvas.width;
let ch = ctx.canvas.height;
let diff;

function progressSim () {
    diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI*2*10); 
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'pink';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw*.5, ch*.5+3, cw);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(35, 35, 30, startPos, diff/10+startPos, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    if (al >= 100) {
        clearTimeout(sim);
    }
    al++;
}

let sim = setInterval(progressSim, 20);


let ctxTwo = document.getElementById('canvasTwo').getContext('2d');
let alTwo = 0;
let startPosTwo = 4.72;
let cwTwo = ctx.canvas.width;
let chTwo = ctx.canvas.height;
let diffTwo;

function progressSimTwo () {
    diffTwo = ((alTwo / 100) * Math.PI*2*10);
    ctxTwo.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctxTwo.lineWidth = 10;
    ctxTwo.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctxTwo.strokeStyle = 'pink';
    ctxTwo.textAlign = 'center';
    ctxTwo.fillText(alTwo + '%', cwTwo*.5, chTwo*.5+3, cwTwo);
    ctxTwo.beginPath();
    ctxTwo.arc(35, 35, 30, startPosTwo, diffTwo/10+startPosTwo, false);
    ctxTwo.stroke();
    if (alTwo >= 50) {
        clearTimeout(simTwo);
    }
    alTwo++;
}

let simTwo = setInterval(progressSimTwo, 20);
```

My attempt using Object constructor:

```
function Gauge(ctx, al, startPos, cw, ch, diff) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.al = al;
    this.startPos = startPos;
    this.cw = cw;
    this.ch = ch;
    this.diff = diff;
    this.progressSim = function () {
        diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI*2*10);
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'pink';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw*.5, ch*.5+3, cw);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(35, 35, 30, startPos, diff/10+startPos, false);
        ctx.stroke();
        if (al >= 100) {
            clearTimeout(this.sim);
        }
        al++;
    };
    this.sim = setInterval(this.progressSim, 20);
}

let gaugeTwo = new Gauge(document.getElementById('canvasTwo').getContext('2d'), 0, 4.72, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

gaugeTwo.progressSim();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

> Code executed by setInterval() runs in a separate execution context
>   than the function from which it was called. As a consequence, the this
>   keyword for the called function is set to the window (or global)
>   object...

([setInterval: the 'this' problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#The_this_problem) - MDN)

When `gaugeTwo.progressSim()` is called, contrary to what you expect, `this` is not a reference to the `Gauge` but to the `window`. So

```
clearTimeout(this.sim)
```

is actually

```
clearTimeout(window.sim)
```

and therefore does nothing.

To fix this, you can `bind()` the `progressSim()` to the right context:

```
this.sim = setInterval(this.progressSim.bind(this), 20);
```

---

As a side note, since you're already calling `progressSim()` in your `Gauge` constructor, you don't need to do it again via `gaugeTwo.progressSim();`.

Comment: Brilliant! this works perfectly. Thanks for your help and the clear explanation :)